# Error al hacer fetch desde STRAPI TypeError: courses.map is not a function

Tags: fetch, next.js, strapi

Ok la cosa es la siguiente, estoy intentando hacer un fetch a STRAPI para obtener datos, sin embargo, me surge el siguiente error

TypeError: courses.map is not a function

He intentado de diferentes formas y lo más que he llegado a conseguir es que no me de el error pero no muestra los datos

```js
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect, React } from "react";

function Coursesfetch() {
  const [courses, setCourse] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Estado para el indicador de carga

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const apiKey =
      "...";
    const url =
      "...";

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`${response.status}`);
      }

      const fetchedData = await response.json();
      setCourse(fetchedData);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }),
    [];

  return (
    <div>
      {error ? (
        <div className="">Ha ocurrido un error: {error.message}</div>
      ) : isLoading ? (
        <div className="">Cargando datos...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="">
          {courses.map((course) => (
            <div key={course.id} className="">
              <h2 className="">{course.name}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Coursesfetch;
```

al hacer un console.log a courses efectivamente está trayendo los datos